# iFrame And URL with &amp; (ampersand)

Tags: iframe, ampersand

I have a page that contains an iFrame point to a URL with parameters. The URL look like: `http://www.myurl.com/page.aspx?parameter1=A&parameter2=B` When it is edited in some of these WYSIWYG the `&` is changed to `&amp;` and that work fine. but rarely my log told me that my `page.aspx` doesn't find the second parameter... if I copy and paste the URL with `&amp;` in the browser `http://www.myurl.com/page.aspx?parameter1=A&amp;parameter2=B` doesn't work that only work inside of the iFrame...

1. We already look into the possibility my page contain something like
   this: `&amp;amp;`
2. I already tested in Firefox4, IE9 and Chrome17 and
   look iFrame render `&amp;` well.
3. Could be other browser that doesn't
   support/render `&amp;` in the iFrame, if so which ones??? Any other
   idea that suggestion???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&amp;` is used to escape an ampersand (`&`) in XML. You should always use `&amp;` instead of just `&` in attributes such as `href`. When pasting it in your browser's address bar, you should't use `&amp;` simply because it doesn't do any form of XML parsing.

Answer (score 2):

Also consider using double quotes around the parameter, e.g. instead of:

```
src = 'http://blahblah.com'
```

do

```
src = "http://blahblah.com"
```

When I changed that, I didn't need to escape the ampersand anymore