# Ampersand in Wordpress Shortcode

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function, shortcode

I made a shortcode for wordpress and the code from functions.php looks like this:

```
return '<div class="video-shortcode"><iframe width="600" height="365" src="/watch.php?file=' . $atts['file'] . '&img=' . $atts['img'] . '" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';
```

When i'm using it, the source code from the post should look like this:

```
<iframe width="600" height="365" src="/watch.php?file=myfile.mp4&img=myimg.jpg" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But for some reason, the ampersand before the 'img' appears as this:

```
&#038;
```

Comment: Just a bit googling...http://wordpress.org/support/topic/ampersands-in-shortcode-attribute-values

Comment: that's not my problem... my problem is in the replacement code, not in the shortcode

Comment: Can you post the entire output? Not just what the ampersand looks like?

Comment: `<div class="video-shortcode"><iframe width="600" height="365" src="/watch.php?file=7002_504_720p.mp4&#038;img=/public/images/ss12preview.jpg" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>`

Comment: @Matt so? do you have any idea?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/unwanted-characters-038

Comment: solved... no idea how tough. I entered this morning and everything was ok

Answer (score 1):

for similar problems to solve you could use [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) function of php

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. There is very little to do that won't be breaking basic Wordpress functions. To break basic WP functions see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605122/how-to-forbidden-wordpress-url-exchange-to-038). For the "right" answer see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824659/iframe-and-url-with-amp-ampersand). I'm using the latter successfully.

Basically use `&amp;` not the other html entity, as this is considered correct XML and is parsed in the iFrame tag by browsers.